# Dynamically reading an array values in x86 Dos assembly

Tags: arrays, assembly, x86-16

I tried to read an array in an repetitive structure but it gives me an error , is there an alternative for the code bellow ?

```
.data 
    aux db 0
    array db 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
.code
main:
    print_array:
    mov dl, array[aux]
    mov ah, 02h
    int 21h
    inc aux
    cmp aux, 9
        je exit
    jmp print_array

    exit:
    mov ah, 4ch
    int 21h        
end main
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *aux* variable serves to index the array. You cannot use a memory based variable this way. Better use an address register for this purpose:

```
      xor si, si
    print_array:
      mov dl, array[si]
      mov ah, 02h
      int 21h
      inc si
      cmp si, 9
      jbe print_array
```